# Java - ArrayList is returning Empty

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, encapsulation

I am creating an array list in a class called Inventory. Here there are methods to add to, delete and get the list. I create a new array list in a new class called combat and set this array list to the one in the Inventory class with a get method.

This is the inventory class part:

```
private ArrayList<String> inventory;

public Inventory() {
    this.inventory = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void addToInventory(String item) {
    inventory.add(item);
    System.out.println("A " + item + " has been added to your inventory");
    printInventory();
}

public void removeFromInventory(String item) {
    inventory.remove(item);
}

public ArrayList<String> getInventory() {
    return inventory;
}
```

This is in the Combat Class:

```
private Inventory inventory = new Inventory();
private ArrayList<String> playerInventory = inventory.getInventory();

public Combat() {

}

@Override
public void setPlayerHit() {
    System.out.println(playerInventory);
```

When I call the print playerInventory line, the arrayList returns []. Yet in the inventory class it has something in as I add an item to it shown in my launcher class:

```
playerInventory.addToInventory(item.getItem(9));
```

I can get this working using public fields but wanted to make use of encapsulation and use getters and setters. Could I possibly get some pointers please?

Comment: You have not given us all necessary elements to reproduce the problem. Can you make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Do you add something to the inventory before printing playerInventory list?

Comment: `playerInventory` is an `ArrayList`. How is that you call `addToInventory()` method on it?

Comment: Could you please provide a sequence of constructor and method calls before and after playerInventory.addToInventory(item.getItem(9)); ?

Comment: Considering that your question was solved, consider learning about dependency injection (if you don't already know it) and a framework like Google Guice. It will be really useful :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just guessing here, but it sounds like you are using separate `Inventory` objects in different parts of the code. They won't share the same internal `inventory` array list and items added to one `Inventory` object won't appear in the other. Make sure that the `Inventory` object you are printing is the same one to which you have added items.

If you want a single global `Inventory` object, you can use a singleton:

```
public class Inventory {
    private static Inventory instance = new Inventory();
    private ArrayList<String> inventory;

    public static Inventory getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    // private constructor to prevent extra copies of the inventory
    private Inventory() {
        inventory = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: exactly my thoughts :), though `private Inventory instance` should be `static`

Comment: @Yazan - Yes, it should, and now it is :). Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

> ***When I call the print playerInventory line, the arrayList returns []***

you are not inserting any string in the Inventory... thus the empty list...

by the way, this is redundant:

```
private ArrayList<String> playerInventory = inventory.getInventory();
```

since you are using by composition an inventory object wich has the  ArrayList

try again  but before doing

```
public Combat() {
    inventory.addToInventory("f1");
    inventory.addToInventory("f2");
}
```

now your inventory object has 2 elements

Comment: i think it would be better if OP passes instance of `Inventory` to Combat ? and just assign it to the member `Inventory ` ?